# How to change the background on each page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am using Ruby on Rails to build a collaborative  artist platform.
I would like the homepage's body background to be yellow, and for example the body of the artist index page to be blue and let's say the body of the artwork index page to be red.
In application.thml.erb I've set `<body class="<%= 'background_yellow' if controller.action_name == 'home' %>">` but that would work only if the homepage's background would be yellow and all the other pages would be white. But here I want each individual page to be a different color.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a class with the controller name somewhere in your HTML code.

```
<body class="<%= "controller_#{controller.name}" %>">
```

then declare some CSS classes in your style-sheet file

```css
.controller_welcome {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.controller_users {
  background-color: pink
}

/* and so on */
```